# dev server page never loads; js assets "pending"

Tags: next.js

I have a next.js project where the dev server is suddenly not loading the page anymore.

The next.js dev server never serves JavaScript assets, and they remain in a "pending" or "stalled" state in Chrome dev tools.

Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools Network panel

[image: 1]

There is no output on the server or front-end console. How do you debug this?

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-aria": "^3.19.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-stately": "^3.17.0",
    ...
  },
```

#### Things I have tried:

- All URLs have this behavior: `http://localhost:3000/`, `http://localhost:3000/specific/paths`
- Delete `.next/` and rebuild
- Delete `node_modules/`, reinstall and rebuild
- Run the dev server on a different port: `next dev -p 1234`
- Add `console.log` statements in various components and see that they all give expected output on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Opening in another browser (Safari in my case) it seems to work fine. I closed and reopened Chrome, and now it works fine.

The bug seems to possibly be related to Chrome itself. Seen on Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (arm64)

Hopefully anyone seeing a similar error can benefit: Try restarting your browser.